# Why do transactions in spring boot tests behave strange?

Tags: spring, jpa, graphql

I am testing a Spring-Boot-Application with graphQL endpoints.
I have a setup-method in my integration tests that loads a database with some predefined users:

```
    @BeforeEach
    protected void setUp() {

        deleteFromTables(
                jdbcTemplate,
                "tableA",
                "tableB",
                ...
                );
        deleteFromTables(jdbcTemplate, "users");

        userRepository.saveAll(getPredefinedUsers());
    }
```

In one of my integration tests, I want to find out if one of my entities has a user attached to it. It is a many-to-many-relationship between the entity and the user:

```
    @ManyToMany private Set<User> recipients;
```

When at the end of the test I want to test that the entity was created with the right user, I get a LazyInitializationException, because the recipient is loaded lazily.
So what I did was putting a @Transactional-annotation on my test-method (or class, I tried both ways)
Now happens a strange thing:
The users I created in my setUp-method are getting lost.
They are still there inside the setup-Method (I can load them with the respository), I can also load them in the test-method itself, but they are lost as soon as I enter the graphQl-Controller, which looks like this:

```
    @GraphQLMutation(name = "createProblem", description = "create a problem ")
    @Transactional(isolation = SERIALIZABLE)
    public Problem createProblem(... some arguments) {

        List<User> users = userRepository.findAll();
    }
```

My guess is that the test-method and the controller have different transactions, so that what happens in one transaction is not seen in the other one. But I have no idea why this is the case and if I can test the controller without switching my ManyToMany-Relationship to EAGER.
Any help is appreciated.
Matthias